# Combining two nested SELECT with DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, select, nested, filemaker

How do I look up DISTINCT values of one table, look for each name in another table and get both the values and their names as a result?

The Beleg table looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ursprungskonto FROM Beleg
WHERE YEAR ( Valuta ) = 2016
```

gets me:

```
1000
1210
1220
1230
```

For each of these values, I need to lookup its name:

```
SELECT Name FROM Geldkonto
WHERE Kontonr = 1000
```

results in:

```
Kasse
```

At the end of the query, I need to have this result:

```
1000    Kasse
1210    OneBankName
1220    AnotherBankName
1230    YABN
```

I'm using SQL-92 (Filemaker).

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try sub-query:

```
SELECT Kontonr , Name FROM Geldkonto
WHERE Kontonr in (SELECT DISTINCT Ursprungskonto FROM Beleg
WHERE YEAR ( Valuta ) = 2016)
```

Comment: This one has an additional benefit: I can easily restrict the result even more using filters on the second table (Geldkonto). Adding, for example `AND Kontonr > 1210`

Comment: It does provide DISTINCT results from table Beleg. Just tried it.

Comment: if answer helped DONT forget to give inspiring upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You could use inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT Beleg.Ursprungskonto, Geldkonto.Name 
FROM Beleg 
INNER JOIN Geldkonto
ON Beleg.Ursprungskonto=Geldkonto.Kontonr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying DISTINCT *after* the join you better do it *before*:

```
SELECT k.Kontonr, k.Name 
FROM Geldkonto AS k
JOIN 
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT Ursprungskonto 
   FROM Beleg
   WHERE YEAR ( Valuta ) = 2016
 ) AS b
ON k.Kontonr = b.Ursprungskonto
```

This is similar to @rev_dihazum's solution, simply using a join instead of a subquery, useful if you need any additional columns from `Beleg`.